# how to handling nested comments in antlr lexer

Tags: antlr4

How to handle nested comments in antlr4 lexer? ie I need to count the number of "/*" inside this token and close only after the same number of "*/" have been received. As an example, the D language has such nested comments as "/+ ... +/"

For example, the following lines should be treated as one block of comments:

```
/* comment 1
   comment 2
   /* comment 3
      comment 4
   */
   // comment 5
   comment 6
*/
```

My current code is the following, and it does not work on the above nested comment:

```
COMMENT : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
        ;
LINE_COMMENT : '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n'  -> channel(HIDDEN)
        ;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Terence Parr has these two lexer lines in his [Swift Antlr4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/swift/swift3/Swift3.g4#L1621-L1623) for lexing out nested comments:

```
COMMENT : '/*' (COMMENT|.)*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
LINE_COMMENT  : '//' .*? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

Comment: Any way to also make a rule for unfinished block comments so that a custom error is raised?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using:

```
COMMENT: '/*' ('/'*? COMMENT | ('/'* | '*'*) ~[/*])*? '*'*? '*/' -> skip;
```

This forces any `/*` inside a comment to be the beginning of a nested comment and similarly with `*/`. In other words, there's no way to recognize `/*` and `*/` other than at the beginning and end of the rule `COMMENT`.

This way, something like `/* /* /* */ a */` would **not** be recognized entirely as a (bad) comment (mismatched `/*`s and `*/`s), as it would if using `COMMENT: '/*' (COMMENT|.)*? '*/' -> skip;`, but as `/`, followed by `*`, followed by correct nested comments `/* /* */ a */`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for Antlr3.

Allows nested comments and '*' within a comment.

```
fragment
F_MultiLineCommentTerm
:
(   {LA(1) == '*' && LA(2) != '/'}? => '*'
|   {LA(1) == '/' && LA(2) == '*'}? => F_MultiLineComment
|   ~('*') 
)*
;   

fragment
F_MultiLineComment
:
'/*' 
F_MultiLineCommentTerm
'*/'
;   

H_MultiLineComment
:   r=  F_MultiLineComment
    {   $channel=HIDDEN;
        printf(stder,"F_MultiLineComment[\%s]",$r->getText($r)->chars); 
    }
;
```

Comment: Remember Antlr3 generated Lexers only have 1 character look-ahead unless you  use predicates like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an ANTLR3 solution, which you can adjust to work in ANTLR4:

I think you can use a recursive rule invocation. Make a non-greedy comment rule for /* ... */ which calls itself. That should allow for unlimited nesting without having to count opening + closing comment markers:

```
COMMENT option { greedy = false; }:
    ('/*' ({LA(1) == '/' && LA(2) == '*'} => COMMENT | .) .* '*/') -> channel(HIDDEN)
;
```

or maybe even:

```
COMMENT option { greedy = false; }:
    ('/*' .* COMMENT? .* '*/') -> channel(HIDDEN)
;
```

I'm not sure if ANTLR properly chooses the right path depending on any char or the comment introducer. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks. I first tried your solution in ANTLR3 itself, before moving to ANTLR4, and it did not work. I just replaced my COMMENT rule with your rule and then ANTLR3 reported errors like: error(100): X.g:syntax error: antlr: MissingTokenException(inserted [@-1,0:0='<missing COLON>',<54>,1927:8] at option)

Answer (score 0):

1. This will handle : '/*/*/' and '/*.../*/'where the comment body is '/' and '.../' respectively.
2. Multiline comments will not nest inside single line comments, therefore you cannot start nor begin a multiline comment inside a single line comment.

   - This is not a valid comment: '/* // */'.
   - You need a newline to end the single line comment before the '*/' can be consumed to end the multiline comment.
   - This is a valid comment: '/* // */ \n /*/'.
   - The comment body is: ' // */ \n /'.  As you can see the complete single line comment is included in the body of the multiline comment.
3. Although '/*/' can end a multiline comment if the preceding character is '*', the comment will end on the first '/' and remaining '*/' will need to end a nested comment otherwise there is a error.  The shortest path wins, this is non-greedy!

   - This is not a valid comment  /****/*/
   - This is a valid comment  /*/****/*/, the comment body is /****/, which is itself a nested comment.
4. The prefix and suffix will never be matched in the multiline comment body.
5. If you want to implement this for the 'D' language, change the '*' to '+'.

`COMMENT_NEST
        : '/*'
          ( ('/'|'*'+)? ~[*/] | COMMENT_NEST | COMMENT_INL )*?
          ('/'|'*'+?)?
          '*/'
        ;`

`COMMENT_INL
        : '//'  ( COMMENT_INL | ~[\n\r] )*
        ;`